# Import Outlook 2010 tasks into thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks

I've a big problem: I've to export MS Outlook 2010 tasks and import them into Thunderbird.

I tried with the simple solution: export a CSV file with tasks but Thunderbird doesn't import anything.
I tried a lot of softwares, like FreeMiCal, PIMescape, outlook2icalv but none of this softwares solve my problem. None of them can create a file that Thunderbird can import.
I tried to convert the CSV file into a ICS file but even this solution didn't work.

I have no problem with calendars.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you sync both of them with a provider of your choice in the cloud? Google Calendar would be my choice. You may be able to use outlook.com

Comment: I need to migrate from outlook to thunderbird. The owner of the PC is my boss, he hasn't google or outlook account. Maybe I can create a new google/outlook account and use that method but is preferable do something like I did for the calendar.